# ASP.NET Core backend and web server

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, webserver

I am currently writing a backend for my web project. I wrote a REST service and used ASP.NET Core to host the files. When using the debugger inside of Visual Studio, I am getting a console and shortly after debug/info messages from the server (it says `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime`).

The problem is that I want to execute the program outside of the IDE, but when I am starting it standalone, it just shows an empty console and nothing happens.

What must I do to host the REST service and web server outside of the IDE?

Comment: Your title says ASP.NET Core but your question itself says ASP.NET (which is different) and your tags are for ASP.NET and .NET (Framework, different to .NET Core). Which one are we dealing with here?

Comment: My frameworks are AspNetCore and NETCore. In my dependencys is just MSSQLServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way
Change Run To IIS

[image]

Comment: well... here we go it runs :)